# I just bought a new computer with Windows 10 and every time I try to open GitBash, I can an error message

Tags: windows, git-bash

The error says:

```
This app can't run on your PC. 
To find a version for your PC, check with software publisher
```

A few minutes ago, It worked when I tried opening it, but I still received the error message.

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have installed the 64 bits version of [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

It should be:

[`Git-2.32.0.2-64-bit.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.32.0.windows.2/Git-2.32.0.2-64-bit.exe) or [`PortableGit-2.32.0.2-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.32.0.windows.2/PortableGit-2.32.0.2-64-bit.7z.exe)

If you do, follow "[How to Fix “This App Can’t Run on your PC” in Windows 10](http://www.bsocialshine.com/2017/01/how-to-fix-this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc.html)" in order to adjust UAC settings.

But I would suspect a wrong version first.